# WCF catching Fault Exceptions of type T or Base type

Tags: wcf, exception

We have a system with a WCF layer.

The WCF services can throw various FaultExceptions, these are exceptions of type:

```
FaultException<MyStronglyTypedException>
```

All strongly types exceptions inherit from a base exception.

```
public class MyStronglyTypedException : MyBaseException
```

I can catch FaultException, but then I do not have access to the Detail property of FaultException.

What I would like to catch is:

```
FaultException<MyBaseException>
```

But this does not seem to be possible.

Is there a way that I can get access to the Detail property of the FaultException, without catching every individual strongly typed exception?

Comment: http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/ankithakur/ExceptionHandlingWCF12282007072617AM/ExceptionHandlingWCF.aspx might be of use

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to be able to catch the strongly typed `FaultException<MyBaseException>` in your client code, you must decorate your service method with the FaultContract attribute for that type:

```
[ServiceContract]
interface IYourService
{
   [OperationContract]
   [FaultContract(typeof(MyBaseException))]
   ResponseType DoSomethingUsefulHere(RequestType request);
}
```

If you don't "declare" those specific types which you want to catch strongly typed `FaultContract<T>` exceptions for, WCF will convert all server side faults into general-purpose `FaultContract` instances.